# Unexpected alignment in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \caption{Medlemstallene i FC Københavns Fan Club.}
  \label{tbl:1}
  \begin{tabular}{l d{4.0} d{4.0} d{4.0} d{4.0}}
   \toprule
    Årstal            & \mc{1999} & \mc{2000} & \mc{2001} & \mc{2002} \\[0.5ex]
    Landsdel          &           &           &           &           \\
   \midrule
    København         & 2511 & 2696 & 3154 & 3927 \\
    Storkøbenhavn     & 1742 & 1881 & 2132 & 2780 \\
    Øst for Storebælt & 1510 & 1668 & 1823 & 2262 \\
    Fyn               &  105 &  118 &  123 &  161 \\
    Jylland           &  369 &  427 &  479 &  594 \\
    Danmark i alt     & 6237 & 6790 & 7711 & 9724 \\
    Udland            &   39 &   37 &   72 &   95 \\
   \midrule
    I alt             & 6276 & 6827 & 7783 & 9819 \\
   \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Medlemstallets udvikling}
    & \mc{\SI{8.8}{\percent}}
    & \mc{\SI{14.0}{\percent}}
    & \mc{\SI{26.2}{\percent}} \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

As can be seen, the numbers in the first row are not properly aligned with the other numbers in the same column. How do I get this alignment and the alignment of the others numbers in the table (as they are now) as well?

P.S. The relative numbers in the bottom row are not improtant here; they should just be centered as they are now.

**Reflection**

I *guess* it has something to do with the fact that the alignment involves a blank space with the same width as a `,` even though there are no decimals in the numbers in the table.

Comment: If your guess is right, adding `\hphantom{,}` after the years or as `<{\hphantom{,}}` to the `\mc` macro would be the right “solution”. Why aren’t you using `siunitx` for the tables?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel If I try `\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1<{\hphantom{,}}}}` I get an upside down exclamation mark after the centered numbers. (The reasons for not using `siunitx` is twofold: (1) The document is from before `siunitx` was released; (2) I'm not familiar with the `siunitx` table syntax.)

Comment: in reading the documentation for the `dcolumn` package, i concur with the sense of your reflection.  if the numbers in the first line are always going to be simply 4-digit years, and the numbers in the body aren't likely to exceed four digits, you could just not use `\mc` in the first line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see. (This was just an example of a table; in other table I have, the numbers in the first row are only to digits long while the numbers in the body are more than that.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I got the correct syntax now. With this approach, doesn't the alignment gets wrong since there is added a space to the centered test and not removed a space from the aligned numbers in the body?

Comment: The only reason they are not aligned is that you explicitly removed the alignment with `\mc{1999}` just using `1999` would align them. What was the intended effect?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The point is that the text could also be `\mc{Year~1999}` and then the numbers in the body wouldn't be centered completely together with begin aligned relativt to each other.

Comment: If you used `Year~1999` rather than mc it would align, as in the siunitx answer accepted if you use `\mc` (or simply `{}` for siunitx) you are explicitly saying you do not want the numbers in that cell to be aligned with the rest of the column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmmm. Good point. Now I'm actually not sure what my problem was...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop »[dcolumn](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)« and let the `S` column types from »[siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)« do the job.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Medlemstallene i FC Københavns Fan Club.}
    \label{tbl:1}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format=4.0]
      S[table-format=4.0]
      S[table-format=4.0]
      S[table-format=4.0]
    }\toprule
      Årstal            & {1999} & {2000} & {2001} & {2002} \\ \addlinespace
      Landsdel          &        &        &        &        \\ \midrule
      København         &   2511 &   2696 &   3154 &   3927 \\
      Storkøbenhavn     &   1742 &   1881 &   2132 &   2780 \\
      Øst for Storebælt &   1510 &   1668 &   1823 &   2262 \\
      Fyn               &    105 &    118 &    123 &    161 \\
      Jylland           &    369 &    427 &    479 &    594 \\
      Danmark i alt     &   6237 &   6790 &   7711 &   9724 \\
      Udland            &     39 &     37 &     72 &     95 \\ \midrule
      I alt             &   6276 &   6827 &   7783 &   9819 \\ \midrule
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{Medlemstallets udvikling} &
      \SI{8.8}{\percent} & \SI{14.0}{\percent} & \SI{26.2}{\percent} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a good solution. I'll try and learn the syntax. Btw. what is the point of the curly braces around the numbers in the first row?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg They exclude the content from being parsed by `siunitx` as a number. The content is then typeset according to `table-text-alignment`  (default `center`) just like you wanted in your original table.

Comment: Great explanation; thank you! (I'll delete this and the first comment before long.)

Comment: while siunitx is fine, the fact that you fixed the alignment here is unrelated to switching between dcolumn and siunitx, siunitx would similarly not align the numbers in the first row if alignment was removed with `\multicolumn{1}{c}` :-)